# как сделать только вертикальную прокрутку в меню?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Здравствуйте,
Есть боковое меню (сайдбар), каждое новое подменю открывается слева направо и имеет фиксированную высоту, необходимо сделать так, чтобы когда пунктов много у подменю, то у него появлялся бы вертикальный скролл, для это прописываю `overflow-y: auto;`, но в таком случае подменю следующего уровня (те что правее) перестают отображаться и появляется горизонтальный скролл для них.
Непонятен механизм `overflow-y: auto;`, почему он влияет на горизонтальное пространство тоже?
Кусочек кода:

```css
.menu__submenu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  outline: solid blue 1px;
}

.menu__item {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<ul class='menu__submenu'>
  <li>пункт 1</li>
  <li>пункт 2</li>
  <li>пункт 3</li>
  <li class='menu__item'>пункт 4
    <ul class='menu__submenu'>
      <li>подпункт1</li>
      <li>подпункт2</li>
      <li>подпункт3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>пункт 5</li>
  <li>пункт 6</li>
  <li>пункт 7</li>
  <li>пункт 8</li>
  <li>пункт 9</li>
  <li>пункт 10</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Все верно. Ведь подменю находиться внутри меню, а у него ширина меньше нужного, вот и скролл появляеться. Что не так то?

Comment: @НазарКалитюк, но у подменю ведь абсолют, а значит он выбивается из потока и может выходить за рамки ширины родителя и так и происходит, пока не задано  `overflow-y`, причем именно `-y`, то есть контроль по вертикали. Непонятен механизм этого свойства

Comment: overflow-y - это по вертикали

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы не отображался горизонтальный скролл, добавьте `overflow-x: hidden;` в класс `.menu`.

Однако это спасет ситуацию лишь отчасти, поскольку ширина меню меньше, чем ширина дочерних элементов.